# Impure property test with SmallCheck and Tasty: resource acquisition

Tags: haskell, smallcheck

I am trying to write property based test with Tasty library and SmallCheck. But I need IO in the property check function and also I need I/O resource. So, I turned existing test into:

```
myTests :: IO Cfg -> TestTree
myTests getResource = testGroup "My Group"
[
    testProperty "MyProperty" $
    -- HOW TO CALL getResource here, but not in
    -- function, so to avoid multiple acquisition
    -- Some{..} <- getResource
    \(x::X) -> monadic $ do -- HERE I WILL DO I/O...
]
```

So, question is: how to call getResource once? So, not in the `\(x::X) -> ...` body but before it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`withResource`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-1.2.3/docs/Test-Tasty.html#v:withResource). According to the documentation, it will convert your `IO Cfg` into an `IO Cfg` that will yield a resource which **"will be acquired only once and shared across all the tests in the tree."**

It also gives you a `Cfg -> IO ()` function where you can free the `Cfg` value if needed. I've left that function as a no-op here for now (`\cfg -> pure ()`), since I don't know the nature of your resource.

```
myTests :: IO Cfg -> TestTree
myTests getResource =
  withResource getResource (\cfg -> pure ()) $ \getResource' ->
    testGroup "My Group"
    [
        testProperty "MyProperty" $ \(x::X) -> monadic $ do
            Some{..} <- getResource'
            -- DO I/O...
    ]
```

Comment: yes, but question is different: imagine that you have multiple `testProperty`, so `getResource'` will be called in each of them, but my goal is to call it **once** for all of them

Comment: @Paul-AG In that case you can put the `withResource` call around the entire `testGroup` call. See my edit